# Yeoman generator-angular routes more than 1 level deep

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am trying to use the Yeoman angular-generator. It builds a basic app fine. But I want to know how I can create routes that are deeper than root level.

For instance every guide I've seen online just show how to create a basic route:

```
yo angular:route myRoute
```

I tried the explicit URI setting as detailed https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#route.

```
yo angular:route myRouteTwo --uri=my/routetwo
```

But this does not appear to work. How then, does this scaffolding tool go about creating routes for deeper resources such as:

/games/:game/levels

At the moment it seems this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late, but here's the answer...

To keep it simple, the URI is the path that the browser will display, what you want is that when you create a route - *e.g. login*- save the controller and the view generated in a custom folder under `scripts>controllers` and `views`, to do so you just have to specify where, like this:

```
yo angular:route custom/path/route
```

This will produce these folder structure:

```
root-app-folder
├── ...
├── scripts
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── custom 
|   |       |── path
|   |           |── route.js
│   │   └── ...
│   └── app.js
├── styles
│   └── ...
└── views
    ├── custom
    |   |── path
    |       |── route.html
    └── ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out the ui- router project. It allows vast increases in route building functionality such as nested routes and x deep routes.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. I'm wondering why the route configuration in app.js does not contain the specified paths.